# Trackpad Setup Linux Mint on Mac Book KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, mouse, macintosh, trackpad

I have been playing around with using Linux Mint on an older Mac Book (2009 era). Linux Mint runs great on this laptop as compared to OS X.

The only major problem I am having is with the trackpad. It is really hard to use. For example if I hold my left pointer finger in the bottom left corner of the trackpad and try and move the mouse with my right pointer finger it will not move until remove my left finger.

The two finger scrolling works, but it is very very fast. The slightest movement puts it to the bottom of the screen.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to setup the trackpad properly? I have tried xserver.xorg.input.mtrack but it wanted to remove a ton of xserver applications. I tried it anyways and xserver would not start back up on reboot, had to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the universe repository is enabled by inspecting `/etc/apt/sources.list` with your favourite editor.

You will need to use sudo to ensure that you have permissions to edit the file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If universe is not included then modify the file so that it does.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe
```

After any changes you should run this command to update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install, type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

To get more information, see [xf86-input-mtrack](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack)

Comment: That is what I tried before.  When installing xerver-xorg-input-mtrack I have to install the dependency xserver-xorg-core.  When installing that it tries to remove tons of packages, mostly xserver-xorg-video... or xserver-xorg-input...  When I tried it last time it broke my GUI after a reboot.

Comment: Try to install `libmtdev1` , `libc6`  , `xorg-input-abi-21` and  `xserver-xorg-core`

Comment: Good new: After installing that and mtrack my trackpad was perfect. Bad news: like I said in my post after reboot Xserver does not load with the following error -- MDM: Xserver not found: /usr/bin/X :0 -audit 0 -auth /var/lib/mdm/:0.Xau

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

Comment: Thanks for that.  I feel like I am going around in circles.  Is there a way to active mtrack on startup now.  After reinstalling xserver-xorg I have lost the nice trackpad functionality.

Comment: try his https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook#Keyboard_.26_Trackpad